# How to use the selected value in a List in a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

my question is very simple and easy for those who are not beginners in web developing..

I have an HTML File

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<div class="toto">

        <select id="myselect" name="Grid">
            <option value="1">VALUE1</option>
            <option value="2">VALUE2</option>
        </select>
        <button id="Submit">CLICK TO SUBMIT</button>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And a script file like this one :-

```
(function ($) {
     init(file)
            { 
            // body of the function with functions inside 
            //functions..
            //functions..
            }

 $(document).ready(function () {
    init("test.json"); /*<---- THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO USE WHAT I SELECTED IN 
THE HTML FILE so instead of writing "test.json", I want it to get automatically 
what I have selected from the list in order to call the function with the right file.*/
      });
    }) (jQuery);
```

Do I have to make a form ? and if yes, how should it be in order to get the variable from the  list?

Or do I have to move the `$(document).ready(fonction()...` in the HTML file between `<script> </script>`

NOTE: I tried the second choice many times but it doesn't work and the function does not load..

Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('#myselect').val()`, and if you want `init(...)` to be called every time the select change, bind an event:

```
$('#myselect').on('change', function(e) {
  init($('#myselect').val());
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I don't get it ?

I know about $("#myselect").val(). but in order to use it, I think I have to use the function init(..) in the HTML file, which doesn't work when I try to use it.

Could you please  add the <script> ...</script> code I have to put in the HTML ?

Comment: Hm, now that I look at the code I see that you've never actually defined the init function. how about `function init()` -- https://jsfiddle.net/j42Lpt7n/

Comment: Okay it works now. I did this :-

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myselect').on('change', function (e) {
        
            init($('#myselect').val());
        });
      
    }); but now I have a problem, which is everytime I change the value in the list, I obtain the new grille with the old one ! which corrputs the page. is there anyway to remove the old one ? @tungd